# STM32 ADC over DMA Continuous Mode Too Greedy

Tags: adc, stm32, dma

I am trying to read ADC data via DMA on an STM32F412. The reading itself works fine but the rest of the program is not executed anymore so it's killed by the watchdog soon.

I have an array of size 50 and have it filled by the ADC in one-channel continuous mode.

There is a small function calculating the average of those 50 values that I call from the "complete" interrupt. If I call this function from main, it works fine.

To slow down the ADC, I set the prescaler from /4 to /8 but that did not help.

What would be the preferred way of slowing down the ADC? Increasing the size of the array seems dirty and might not buy me much.

A timer interrupt maybe?

Comment: What is the sample rate, what timer did you use, post your ADC, DMA, TIM initialization code...

Comment: You might want to do contious ADC without the DMA where you make the sum to compute the everage little by little on each interrupt and compute the average every 50 cycles.
Rather than "slowing down" the ADC, ask yourself what the ideal sampling period is.  Remember the Nyquist algorithm.
Averaging the 50 samples inside the interrupt upon data completion may be too long for your program/watchdog.  Resetting the watchdog inside an interrupt may seem a bad idea, but there are complex watchdog methods available in the STM32 that allow mitigating the risks of WDOG  resets inside the interrupt.

Comment: Something is really missing from your description here.  DMA should not be blocking your code from executing to at least service the watchdog, unless you are mistakenly doing a blocking wait on it.  And you shouldn't do substantial calculations in an ISR.  It sounds like there are issues with the way the pieces of your program and the DMA engine fit together, but as no real details are provided in your question it's hard for anyone to help.

Comment: In other words, we can't debug your software unless you show it to us.

Comment: @rom1nux I did not use any timer yet. I am considering it now but wanted to ask first. ... Thanks for the other hints. The code is entangled in a bigger code base. I will try to create a minimal example over the weekend.

Comment: @Bugfinger Your ISR is probably continuously fired and you stay in dead ISR loop. (Tell us the targeted sample rate). The ADC and DMA can be sequenced by a timer. Init and tell them you want 50 points every X ms. Use double buffering, as 2 flags somewhere to tell is_buffer_1_ready (HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallback) and is_buffer_2_ready (HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback) and process them in your main.

Comment: @Bugfinger Dont forget to release the flags, Criticial section for the flags, and don't forget to check overrun when flags are already set in HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallback or HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback . 
With this method you can set the time between two DMA interrupt and you have control of the load.